# setting/putting number value in a sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, reference, preferences, shared

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.save2:
        s = text.getText().toString();
        number = Float.parseFloat(num.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString("sharedtext",s);
        editor.putFloat("sharednum",number);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this,"save2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.load2:
        String returner = shared.getString("sharedtext","Returner fail");
        float returnnum = shared.getFloat("sharednum","number fail");
        //there is a red mark here^^^^^^^^^(getfloat)
        text.setText(returner);
        //num.set.......how will
        Toast.makeText(this,"load2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.page2:
        intent= new Intent(this,SharedPreferencesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"page2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
```

//there is a red mark here^^^^^^^^^(getfloat) -an error that keeps me switching into getInt and getFloat

//num.set.......how will i set a number value?

thanks

Comment: change it to float returnnum = shared.getFloat("sharednum","0.0");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457215/how-does-one-declare-the-type-of-an-android-preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to set a default value, when you are trying to getvalues from preferences, like below:

```
float returnnum = shared.getFloat("sharednum",0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`float returnnum = shared.getFloat("sharednum","number fail");`

Change "number fail" to a number of type `float`. This parameter represents the default value, so you cannot use a string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  float returnnum = shared.getFloat("sharednum",0f);
```